# Javascript:window.print(); not working

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple link to print a page I created. I'm using Google Chrome. But that link is not working. When I checked my console log, I'm getting this message when I click the link:

**Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Here's the HTML I'm using to create the print:

```html
<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print page</a>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: your snip works fine - did it get redefined? can you provide more context?

Comment: your script working fine for me --> https://jsfiddle.net/sxuwzzd0/

Comment: This happens if we call our method recursively, but do not have any base condition to break the infinite loop. Then **StackOverflow** happens. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. It was pretty dumb.

I had two links on a different page to print the page. For one link I was using a function to print the page `onclick=PrintMe()`. The other link was the above snippet. `<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print me</a>`.

It seems these two were fighting eachother. That's what the error means.

Thanks though!

Comment: I had same problem. I had defined a method named `print` then I was calling `window.print()`. It seems this method calling is being recursive. So I renamed my method to `printMe` and it is working fine.

Comment: Its Works with Typescript And Angular

Answer (score 7):

Try replacing with the below

```html
<a onclick="window.print()">Print page</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Wait, this one's a bit silly. How can the 'href' attribute be an action. You have to use Jquery and give the `<a>` or a tag a class and then trigger it, and then do:

```
.('TheID').on('click', function(){
      javascript:window.print();
});
```

Or there is an even simpler solution to this, you can just add this:-

Print page

Comment: You can actually perform javascript "actions" in the href attribute by prepending it with "javascript:"